# Dosbox - How and where to add `mount` commands?

Tags: macos

Looking at this:

https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/DOSBox_and_Mac_OS_X

I read

> Editing DOSBox preferences
>
> After you first run DOSBox, go to the ~/Library/Preferences/ folder and open the newly > created file DOSBox 0.74 Preferences. The exact folder name in the Finder may vary, depending on the language you use for OS X.
>
> By editing this file, you can set the system settings and initialization values that define your emulated environment. You can also add MOUNT commands to the AUTOEXEC section at the bottom of the configuration files, so that you do not have to type them in every time you start DOSBox.

I can run DOSBOX and also an abbandonware. No violacion of copyright.

I cannot find this file

[image]

My question is: how to add mount commands ? and where?

> I have Monterey 12.4 installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into the Library/Preferences folder *within* your home directory, not the global Library as shown in the screenshot.